# How to use BroadcastReceiver in Xamarin with C #?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I need to generate a notification when the app is in the background, but I'm not sure how to start Broadcastreceiver

Comment: Xamarin has a complete guide on the subject: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/broadcast-receivers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:
1. `LocalBroadcastManager` will send messages only to your application

```
Intent message = new Intent("com.xamarin.example.TEST");
// If desired, pass some values to the broadcast receiver.
intent.PutExtra("key", "value");
Android.Support.V4.Content.LocalBroadcastManager.GetInstance(this).SendBroadcast(message);
```

2. `Context.SendBroadcast` methods will send messages to the entire system

```
Intent message = new Intent("com.xamarin.example.TEST");
// If desired, pass some values to the broadcast receiver.
intent.PutExtra("key", "value");
context.SendBroadcast(intent);
```

from [Xamarin guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/broadcast-receivers/)

Comment: Thank you very much! It helped a lot.